# SVA: Use of implication (|=>) vs sequence?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

SystemVerilog Assertion properties can be built with implication operators `|=>` and sequences `##1`

For example :

```
property P1;
  @(posedge clk)
    A ##1 B |=> C ##1 D;
endproperty
```

Above we have used `A ##1 B` as an enabling sequence (antecedent) and `C ##1 D` as the fulfilling sequence (consequent).

I do not see why it could not be rewritten as :

```
property P2;
  @(posedge clk)
    A ##1 B ##1 C ##1 D;
endproperty
```

When and why would you choose implication `|=>` over a sequence `##1` ?

Comment: This isn't Verilog - what's the etiquette around here for changing question tags?

Comment: I think most people would just edit the question, and leave a clear 'edit summary'. Also not sure how much we distinguish between verilog and SystemVerilog these days since the LRMs were rolled in to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above properties are the same for the sequence passing, however the failure conditions do not match.

If they are all 1's then `A ##1 B ##1 C ##1 D;` and `A ##1 B |=> C ##1 D;` are true.

If we have A as 1 then the rest 0's:

`A ##1 B ##1 C ##1 D;` fails and `A ##1 B |=> C ##1 D;` would pass.

The latter is not considered a failure due to the conditions of the enabling sequence not being met.